# Pass string from service to intent

Tags: android, string, android-intent, service

To pass data from my service to my intent I am using following code:

```
private String stringVar;
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Messenger messenger = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");

                try {

                    Message message = new Message();

                    int arg = var;
                    message.arg1 = arg;

                                //how can i add stringVar?

                    messenger.send(message);
                } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
                    Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
                }
            }
```

and in the activity:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {

            int i = message.arg1;

            Log.e("Handler", "Succesfully transfered: " + (Integer.toString(i)));
        };
    };
```

But right now as you can see I only retrieve the arg1, which is an int. How can I also make sure I am passing the String value to my Intent?

Comment: did you read Message documentation ? (also, what string value ?)

Comment: I edited my post to make it a little bit more clear, and yes, I thought it was only possible to pass int's in the documentation..

Comment: and so did you read again Message documentation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a Bundle and put multiple values inside of that bundle then pass it over.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", str);
message.setData(bundle);
```